# How to reference ruby classes defined in a different project

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
project1: contains app\models\foo.rb (ActiveRecord facade for foo object)
project2: I would like to fetch all foo's in project2.
```

How do I reference foo from project1 over here, so that I can avoid code duplication corresponding to fetching information from the same table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to share data then [ActiveResource](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveResource/Base.html) should do the trick. I'd recommend watching [the Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/94-activeresource-basics) to get you started.

If it's just the class code you're trying to share, then I'd say just put it in a gem.

Comment: I am a newbie, is there a sample gem I could take a look at to achieve code sharing?

Comment: You could create your own gem, it's really easy with engines in Rails 3.1. Just go to a new directory and run `rails plugin new my_gem_name --full`. Edit your .gemspec file and then develop it like a regular Rails app. Run `gem build` to create a `.gem` file you can install and include in your Gemfile or just use `gem 'my_gem_name', :path => /path/to/my_engine`.

Answer (score 0):

I think there are 2 approaches to do that:

1. Use 2 databases in one Rails app. There are some related questions on stackoverflow. See as example [How do i work with two different databases in rails with active records?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1226182/how-do-i-work-with-two-different-databases-in-rails-with-active-records)
2. Use the [Rails ActiveResource](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveResource/Base.html) to do that. It is a lightweight approach, to use external resources by a REST interface. However, you drive 2 applications, and have calls between them. Depending on the operating system, this may cost more runtime than the other approach.