# Ruby ActiveRecord Dynamic Model creation

Tags: ruby, activerecord, multiple-databases

I am trying to establish a multiple DB connection with ActiveRecord.Currently I need to insert data into total 2 Databases. There is a possibility for increase in the No.Of databases.

So I created 2 classes dynamically which will Extend from `ActiveRecord::Base`

```
Object.const_set("Connection1",Class.new(ActiveRecord::Base) do
  self.abstract_class = true
  self.establish_connection({
    :host=>"localhost", :username=>"root", :password=>"root", :database=>"db1", :encoding=>"utf8", :adapter=>"mysql2"})
end)

Object.const_set("Connection2",Class.new(ActiveRecord::Base) do
  self.abstract_class = true
  self.establish_connection({
    :host=>"localhost", :username=>"root", :password=>"root", :database=>"db2", :encoding=>"utf8", :adapter=>"mysql2"})
end)
```

Then I created Dynamic models extends from each class accordingly

```
Object.const_set("ConnectionUser1",Class.new(Connection1) do
  self.table_name = 'user'
  def self.foo
    all.count
  end
end)

Object.const_set("ConnectionUser2",Class.new(Connection2) do
  self.table_name = 'user'
  def self.foo
    all.count
  end
end)
```

Then when I tried to call foo method

```
p ConnectionUser1.foo
p ConnectionUser2.foo
```

It gives me **ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished** Error.

**I heard that if the model doesn't have connection ActiveRecord will take connection of their parent**.

So according to this ConnectionUser1 should use the connection of Connection1 and ConnectionUser2 use the connection of Connection2.

Then why `ActiveRecord` fails to Establish Connection?

Any help will be appreciated.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at below link which shows that how to use multiple database with ActiveRecord.

[How do i work with two different databases in rails with active records?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1226182/how-do-i-work-with-two-different-databases-in-rails-with-active-records#answer-1226268)