# Rails use multiple db

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, database

In my rails app i need to use more than one db in app. But how can i told rails, that this table must be from this db, another - from another. I'm using mysql.
now config looks like this:

```
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: Mycorp_development
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password: root
  socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
```

and one of model (i know that is not in rails-way, but db is non-my)

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :ART_ID, :ART_ARTICLE_NR,  :ART_SUP_ID,  :ART_DES_ID,  :ART_COMPLETE_DES_ID, :ART_CTM, :ART_PACK_SELFSERVICE,  :ART_MATERIAL_MARK, :ART_REPLACEMENT, :ART_ACCESSORY, :ART_BATCH_SIZE1, :ART_BATCH_SIZE2, :QUANTITYM, :PRICEM
  set_table_name "ARTICLES"
  set_primary_key :ART_ID
end
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do i work with two different databases in rails with active records?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1226182/how-do-i-work-with-two-different-databases-in-rails-with-active-records)

Comment: you can refer http://paramitech.com/2009/08/rails-application-with-multiple-database/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ActiveRecord hasn't been made to communicate to two different databases.

Sure https://github.com/cherring/connection_ninja seems to provide a workaround, I haven't tested it but I'd very careful using this.

You're putting yourself in a case that wasn't planned by the developers, meaning you could hit some walls and having to dig into AR internals to understand what's going on.

Given you really need to handle two databases, I strongly suggest considering these two alternatives that both support multiple databases out of the box :

- Sequel : http://sequel.rubyforge.org/documentation.html
- DataMapper : http://datamapper.org/

They work nicely with Rails 3.

Comment: i know it), but for developing must to connect to other db, becouse on my drive now i haven't so much free space: so i need to get some ables from another project

Comment: Ah if you don't mix the records, you should not have many issues then by using the workaround. :)