# How do I work with a LEGACY database in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, legacy-database

I'm working on a Rails web site that profiles stock mutual funds and ETFs.  I ALREADY HAVE a separate Ruby script that runs nightly and populates a Postgres database with data on these mutual funds and ETFs.

Chapter 6 of Rails tutorial isn't quite what I'm looking for.  The differences between what I'm trying to do and what chapter 6 of Rails tutorial does are:
1.  In my Rails site, there is no need to create a database, because it has already been populated.  So I don't think I need to use "rails generate" or "rake db:migrate".  (Or am I wrong?)
2.  My Rails site only reads data and does not add, delete, or edit data.

Comment: Have a look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1226182/how-do-i-work-with-two-different-databases-in-rails-with-active-records

Comment: You don't have to create migrations.  Just create your models.  If the database table does not match the model name, you can use `set_table_name`.  If you don't use the Rails standard for foreign keys, you'll have to specify the foreign key in the relationships.

Comment: @mind.blank, that question is more about connecting to multiple DBs within an app.

Comment: @SeanHill you should add your comment as an answer

Comment: Done.  Thanks... I had forgotten about this question.  :-)

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to create migrations. Just create your models. If the database table does not match the model name, you can use `set_table_name` for older versions of Rails or `self.table_name = 'table_name'` for newer versions. If you don't use the Rails standard for foreign keys and primary keys, you'll have to specify those as well.

For example:

```
# Assuming newer versions of Rails (3.2+, I believe)

class ETF < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.primary_key = 'legacy_id'
  self.table_name = 'legacy_etfs'
  has_many :closing_prices, foreign_key: 'legacy_etf_id'
end

class ClosingPrice < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.primary_key = 'legacy_id'
  self.table_name = 'legacy_closing_prices'
  belongs_to :etf, foreign_key: 'legacy_etf_id'
end
```

Comment: If you have 30+ models, that's a lot of typing  You might want to check out the "schema to scaffold" gem.  https://github.com/frenesim/schema_to_scaffold - scaffolds create migrations, controllers, models, and views.  Validations, relationships, and 'non-rails-named' tables and keys, are defined in your models automatically.