# Can you create a ruby api application on top of existing schema?

Tags: ruby, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-3

I am fairly new to Ruby on Rails.  I am using it to create a web API application and was wondering if instead of creating a schema based on my Model, can I do the reverse?  E.g. is it possible to create model that would fit with an already existing schema?  Something like that would be fairly easy in Java World using JPA but I am not so sure about Rails using DSL for databases.

Do I have to manually change the migration files in this case? If yes, is there an easy/recommended way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: You might want to consider [`activeresource`](https://github.com/rails/activeresource) because you already use Rails.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16115890/how-do-i-work-with-a-legacy-database-in-rails

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that you have to do is to add ActiveRecords with the name of your tables.

https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html

And yes there is way to reverse engineer it.

There is pretty good article about that: https://codeburst.io/how-to-build-a-rails-app-on-top-of-an-existing-database-baa3fe6384a0