# how can i connect to two database servers in rails app parallally?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, sql-server

in my rails app, i want to connect to two database servers. one is `ms-sql(microsoft sql server)` and other is `mysql` database. how can i connect to both servers in parallel. i know some people use `sqlite3` in  development, and in production `postgres` database. i dont want in this way. what i want is either it is development or production i want to connect to both the databases in parallel. how can i? in what way i need to write the `database.yml file`. is there any gem for connecting to `ms-sql server` database?

```
default: &default
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  pool: 5
  username: mysql-user-name
  password: mysql-password
  socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

  adapter: ms-sql like gem? 
  encoding: utf8
  pool: 5
  username: ms-sql-user-name
  password: ms-sql-password
  socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock



  development:
  <<: *default
  database: template_development
```

Comment: You can find waht you are looking for here I think http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1825844/multiple-databases-in-rails

Answer (score 1):

I've done [something similar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1226268/1143732), although there's a major problem when it comes to the likes of `has_many :through`:

```
#lib/parallel.rb
class Parallel < ActiveRecord::Base
   establish_connection "other_#{RAILS_ENV}"
end

#config/database.yml
development:
  adapter: mysql
  database: development
  username: root
  password:
  host: localhost

other_development:
  adapter: mysql
  database: otherdb_development
  username: root
  password:
  host: localhost
```

This allows you to inherit from the "other connection" db:

```
#app/models/user.rb
class User < Parallel
   ...
end
```

Although this works perfectly (albeit with some issues pertaining to the `schema` of the other db), you'll have a major issue when trying to use the likes of `has_many :through`.

I don't have any specifics, but you'd have to be careful with mixing your associations between db's with this functionality.